# On continuity of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $T:[0,1) \to [0,1)$ to be aperiodic i.e $\forall x \in [0,1)$, $O(x)$ is infinite.$( O(x)=\{x,T(x),T^2(x), \cdots\})$ and $T$ is not continuous. Imagine $\mu$ is any $T$-invariant probability measure on $[0,1)$. It is written in my note that $\mu$ is continuous because $T$ is aperiodic, but it is not kind of trivial to me. could anyone help me understand why the measure $\mu$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mu (\{x\})>0$ and $T^{n_k}(x), k=1,2...$ are all distinct.  Then $\{T^{n_1}x\}, \{T^{n_2}x\} ,\{T^{n_3}x\},...$ are disjoint sets and they all have the same positive measure which makes $\mu [0,1)=\infty$. Hence, $\mu (\{x\})=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Is the measure zero of any singleton equals that measure is continuous?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of a continuous measure. In some (pre-mesaure theoretic)  Statistics books they define a continuous measure as one with  a density  but that is not what is meant here. @RezaYaghmaeian

Comment: @RezaYaghmaeian You can refer to K L Chung's A course in Probability Theory for the definition of  a  continuous measure.